# MIPS Reverse Integer

Tags: assembly, integer, mips, reverse, zero

i'm working on MIPS algorithm for reverse an integer.... the code is this:

```
    li $t3, 0
    move $a2, $t3
    beq $s0, 0, goto
loop1:
     divu $s0, $t1      # Divide number by 10
     mflo $s0           # $s0 = quotient
     mfhi $t2           # $t2 = reminder
     mul $a2, $a2, $t1  # reverse=reverse*10
     addu $a2, $a2, $t2 #         + reminder    
     bne $s0, 0,loop1   
goto: 
     move $s0, $a2
     j nextalgorithm    # Here $a2 contains the reversed integer
```

but the problem it's with 0 in the input number.... example: 010020 became ---> 2010

how can i fix this code? thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your input and output are numeric (as opposed to text) then of course leading zeroes are omitted. As such your input isn't `010020` it's `10020`. Reversing that would produce `02001`, which with leading zeroes omitted again is `2001` and that's exactly what your code produces (contrary to what you claim).

If you want to keep leading/trailing zeroes you have to use a text format or pad to some fixed length.

Comment: Example for what? Using text? That's just your everyday reverse-a-string problem.

Comment: example for transform int to string, reverse the string, and trasform again in int.... i've understand well your 1st comment ?

Comment: That won't work. If you have numeric input, you don't have any leading zeroes on it since numbers can have any number of leading zeroes without changing the value. `100` and `000100` are both one hundred. Similarly you can't return leading zeroes if your output is numeric. The text approach would only work if your input and output were strings and not numbers.

Comment: but the problem is also for the double/triple... zero beetween 2 numbers... example... 10001 became 101... about this there are a solutions ?

Comment: `10001` I correctly get back unchanged with your code (the only thing I added was a `li $t1, 10` which I assume you have too). Embedded zeroes work.